# What is the best way to check the current getFreeBusyStatus of a user at a specific time using EWS?

Tags: java, android, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

There seems to be a decent amount of ways to check attendee availability and return the free busy status like this:

```
for (AttendeeAvailability attendeeAvailability : results.getAttendeesAvailability()) {
                if (attendeeAvailability.getErrorCode() == ServiceError.NoError) {
                    for (CalendarEvent calendarEvent : attendeeAvailability.getCalendarEvents()) {
                        System.out.println("Calendar event");
                        System.out.println("  Start time: " + calendarEvent.getStartTime().toString());
                        System.out.println("  End time: " + calendarEvent.getEndTime().toString());
                        System.out.println("  FreeBusy Status: " + calendarEvent.getFreeBusyStatus().toString()); // USE THISSSSS

                        if (calendarEvent.getDetails() != null) {
                            System.out.println("  Subject: " + calendarEvent.getDetails().getSubject());
                            // Output additional properties.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

However, I'm wondering if you can get a user's availability at a specified time (for example, a method like "getUserStatus") and return if the user is free, busy, tentative, etc.

getBusyFreeStatus is tied to a calendar event so I'm not sure if this is the best way to get a user's current status.

Thanks!

Comment: Nice question, but I don't think so. My guess would be to find all events on that date, then go through them and check the times and status. Note that you have to handle overlapping events.